# Send User Input to windows terminal via python3

Tags: python-3.x, windows, batch-file, terminal, user-input

I have to execute a programm in batch-mode, that will ask for user credentials in a windows terminal. Unfortunately I can only send the username and not the password as input arguments, when starting the programm. Therefore I want to send the predefined password to the terminal (which needs to be visible for the user) via python3. It's the only remaining user input that is asked by the programm.
Since it's a windows machine, I can't use pexpect. I also tried wexpect, subprocess.communicate() and stdin.write(), but it doesn't seem to work.
As a minimal example for testing, I wrote the following batch file, asking for a password:

askPWD.bat

```
@echo off
echo START ASK PWD
set "psCommand=powershell -Command "$pword = read-host 'Enter Password' -AsSecureString ; ^
    $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword); ^
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do set password=%%p

echo %password%
```

Some examples of what I've tried so far:

wexpect:

```
import wexpect
child = wexpect.spawn('C:\\Desktop\\askPWD.bat')
child.expect('Enter Password:')
child.sendline('userinput')
print(child.before)
```

subprocess:

```
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
    p = Popen('start cmd /K C:\\Desktop\\askPWD.bat', shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)    
    output= p.communicate(input=b'userpassword\n')[0]
    print(output.decode())
```

```
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
    proc = Popen('start cmd /K C:\\Desktop\\askPWD.bat', shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
    proc.stdout.readline()
    proc.stdin.write('userpassword\n')
```

The desired output would be, that python sends the password to terminal and the batch-mode programm continues with it's execution.

Answer (score 0):

So, for the beginning, Batch files, and, i think, any programming language, can't watch in live something happening in the computer without a re-read or, basically, try to find it again.
You need to make a new batch label to verify if the password is been seted or not. Using an basic exemple:

```
:verify
if exist continue goto continue
goto verify
```

That program will continue until the file or folder named only "continue" (not case sensitive because is without quotation marks)

In your case, in password case, you make the batch verify if exist, in somewhere, or in some variable, an valid password, using an folder with `mkdir` or something. I don't recommend use files, is complicated.
To erase folders is just `rd (folder)`, and no one will see the folder. You can use the system variable `%temp%` or `%tmp%` to armazenate the folder. Is visible by every single program, but that is your advantage.

I hope that i helped you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but I don't quite understand it. I'm sorry my programming knowledge is not very profound, so here's what I was thinking: 
The batch code asks for the pwd and wait for a user input. It continues running as soon as the user hits "enter" and since it's the only user input that's asked for, my plan was to send the pwd to the stdout and as soon as the batch asks for the user-input it will recieve the pwd from the python code. 
Do I still need to verify if the password has been seted?

Comment: No, post your code here and i can analize that for you, but, a recommendation: batch files are NOT for passwords, because they need an external program or the password is been cracked with a simple reverse-engineer, file find or just clicking in "edit"...
Like:

set /p try=Type pwd:
if %pwd% equ 123 goto sucessful

if you put the string: "1 equ 1 goto sucessful " you will, without pwd, acess that... if the password is checked in a if condition, even without knows the batch label: "1 equ 1 & echo ", will show everything in the if condition... even if has reverse commas...
I hope i helped

Comment: To store passwords i recommend mysql, or, in minimal, you create a encrypt/decryptation tool with batch... is not too hard, i can teach you, even if it has some limitations, the password isnt that easy to decrypt. Is like an HASH, but maded by you!
I hope i helped you.

Comment: And, basically, if the password is CORRECT, some program will create a folder named "continue", and your batch script will analize if it exist... if exist, you pass. Simple.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. 
The code I want to get running in combination with python is already posted in my initial question. So my goal is to forward the password (let's assume insecurely saved, hardoced in my python script) to the batch file, that asks for user input through windows cmd. 
There's already an existing script I use for encrypting passwords. That already works fine and therefore the secure-issue doesn't bother me. The link I'm missing is, as already said, to forward smth (right or wrong password) to the cmd, in which the batch asks for userinput.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post the full code here. So my aim is to come up with a python code that sends input to the terminal, when the batch-file asks for it. Therefore I posted this minimalist example, which behaves the same as the "original" one. And I'm not allowed to change the batch, so therefore I need to get a python script running.